# Angular - How to use multiple css class with multiple condition in button in angular?

Tags: css, angular

How can I use multiple CSS class based on the conditions?

```
 <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="row p-0 m-1">
      <button [ngClass]="product.button1 === 'C' || product.button1 === '( )' || product.button1 === '%' || product.button1 === '&divide' ? 'btn-blue-text btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1'" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Rad')">{{product.button1}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('Deg')">{{product.button2}}</button>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('x!')">{{product.button3}}</button>
      <button [ngClass]="product.button4 === '=' ? 'btn-blue btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1'" type="button" (click)="clickNumber('(')">{{product.button4}}</button>
 </div>
```

The above code is working only on `product.button === 'C'`, but not working on other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container . For example you have a div inside the ng-container and it your ts file declare a variable

> products: any=[];

and you have a condition where the variable is incremented every time a user clicks on that div and you make use as follows

This is show when it meets the condition

```
<ng-container *ngIf="products.length !=0">
 <div> <div>
<ng-container>
```

or else show this div

```
<ng-container *ngIf="products.length ==0">
 <div> <div>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngClass]="{ 'class1': condition1, 'class2': condition2, 'class3': condition3, 'class4': condition4, ... }"
```

Comment: Hi this is only working in first condition. In my case condition is different but the class is same any suggestion?

Comment: This is my code:- `<button [ngClass]="(product.button1 === 'C') ? 'btn-blue btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1' : (product.button1 === '( )') ? 'btn-blue btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary col p-1 m-1'" type="button" (click)="self[product.link]()">{{product.button1}}</button>`.

Comment: Well, you can refactor it and use a single method that merges every condition, so your code is more clean. E.g.: <button class="col p-1 m-1 btn-outline-secondary" [ngClass]="{ 'your-specific-condition1-class': isCondition1True(...), 'your-specific-condition-2-class': isCondition2True(...) }"; and so on. Note that I moved the common classes into the class property so everything is more readable.

Comment: So you can have a method outside (in the Component) like isCondition1True(elementRef) { const btnValue = elementRef.... // grab the value; if (btnValue === 'C' || btnValue === '( )') { // return true ; else return false; } }